# Get previous two months date based on a parameter value

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a datetime parameter value in stored proc which will receive value like '30-Sep-2011' and the value will always be the last day of the month! How can i get the previous two months date based on the received value? And the values also must be the last day of the month!

Comment: What is the SQL Server version ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
declare @TwoMonthsBack datetime 

select @TwoMonthsBack= dateadd(dd,-1, DateAdd(MM,-2,DateAdd(dd,1,@YourInputDateParam)))
```

Example:

```
declare @YourInputDateParam datetime = '30-Sep-2011'
declare @TwoMonthsBack datetime 
select @TwoMonthsBack= dateadd(dd,-1, DateAdd(MM,-2,DateAdd(dd,1,@YourInputDateParam)))

SELECT @TwoMonthsBack
```

Prints:

```
2011-07-31 00:00:00.000
```

Explanation:

Take the input date (always last day of month, as specified); add one day (will make it first day of the next month - October 1st from the example); subtract 2 months (will make it first day of 1 month ago from input date - August 1 on the example); subtract 1 day (will make it last day of 2 months ago from input date - July 31st on the example)

Comment: Not the last day of July... You could add a day, subtract two months, then subtract a day I suspect though.  `@TwoMonthsBack=DateAdd(DD, -1, DateAdd(MM,-2, DateAdd(DD, 1, @YourInputDateParam)))`

Comment: @Mootinator. I see what you mean. I just realized that July has 31 days! heheh. Let me fix it. ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @start_date datetime
--declare @start_date1 datetime
declare @end_date datetime
--set @start_date1 =(select DATEDIFF(mm,GETDATE() ,getdate()))
set @start_date =(select DATEADD (mm,-10,getdate()))

set @end_date = (select convert(varchar(20),GETDATE()))
print @end_date
print @start_date
```